# Blazor StateHasChanged does not work correctly

Tags: c#, blazor

```
@if (_loading)
{
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
....
@code 
{
 private bool _loading
...
private void Search()
{
_loading = false;
StateHasChanged();
Mails.Clear();
Licenses.Clear();
Callings.Clear();
Supports.Clear();
Leads.Clear();
search();
_loading = true;
StateHasChanged();
}
```

The DOM does not change at runtime. Only if you change the value of _loading twice, but if you change it only once, it works. However, I definitely need to do this twice. So I make a progressbar. How fix it?

Comment: @viveknuna That is a terrible advice.

Comment: @GSerg why? because he is calling StateHasChanged twice. Do you think there can be better options?

Comment: @viveknuna Because it blocks the thread. And yes, there are [better options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#an-asynchronous-handler-involves-multiple-asynchronous-phases).

Comment: @GSerg thank you. As suggested by GSerg, Mr Kruizer please use `await Task.Delay(1000);` between these two lines StateHasChanged(); Mails.Clear();

Comment: @viveknuna The `await Task.Delay(1000)` is to demonstrate in the example that the rendering actually occurs four times. It would have occured four times without the `await Task.Delay(1000)`, it's just that it would be too fast for you to notice. The point is to let the framework do its job by using `async`, not to inject artificial delays.

Comment: You don't need to wait 1000ms, but you do need to `await` something for each re-render that you want - and an `await Task.Delay(1)` or `await Task.Yield()` is usually all that is required - to yield the thread and allow the renderer to process the request from StateHasChanged()

Comment: Which progress bar component or script are you using? And what does `search` do? Why isn't it asynchronous? Any Blazor calls that could block are asynchronous, eg calling a remote service. This means that `search()` most likely intentionally blocked an async operation

Comment: @viveknuna that's terrible advice, squared. It's terrible to begin with. Browser tabs are single-threaded though, so `Thread.Sleep` will freeze the entire tab, for absolutely no benefit.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already got the suggestion from GSerg

Comment: @viveknuna delete the comments then. This is really terrible advice. I'm writing a reporting application in Blazor WASM right now and the very suggestion of `Thread.Sleep` made me cringe.

Comment: No offense, but if you're this new, instead of blaming Blazor for "not working," you might want to ask, "What am I, the new programmer, missing here?"

Comment: Completely true. This thread should be closed. This user has not visited his question for 14 hours, and I wonder if ever he'll do that.

Comment: so the answer is what, exactly?  I'm not sure what is being said, besides StateHasChanged() requests only work on the main thread and doesn't work asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your quoted code doesn't show who calls search, here's a version that works, and uses `Search` in both the component load events and driven from a button click.

Note it's async and uses `Tasks`.  `await Task.Delay(3000);` emulates your code.

```
@page "/Demo"
<h3>Demoblock</h3>
@if (_loading)
{
    <div class="bg-warning p-2 m-2">Loading...</div>
}
else
{
    <div class="bg-success p-2 m-2">Loaded</div>
}
<div class="p-2 m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="DoSearch">New Search</button>
</div>
@code
{
    private bool _loading;

    private async Task Search()
    {
        _loading = true;
        // not needed
        //StateHasChanged();
        //Mails.Clear();
        //Licenses.Clear();
        //Callings.Clear();
        //Supports.Clear();
        //Leads.Clear();
        //search();
        //Emulate doing the above work
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        _loading = false;
        // not needed
        // StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Search();
    }

    private async Task DoSearch(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        await Search();
    }
}
```

What's happening is this in pseudo code:

```
Set up a Task when you run the Event - such as OninitializedAsync, On ParametersSetAsync, Mouse/Keyboard Event
If Task has not completed 
{
    Render the Component.
    Now Wait for the Task to Complete
}
Render the Component
```

The key here is that the first render only occurs if your event returns a Task and yields.

1. If you event yields but returns a void then there's no task for the handler to wait on so runs the last render before the event completes.
2. If your code is synchronous i.e. no yields, it completes so the Task has completed and only the second render occurs.

Comment: Your pseudo code is a little bit vague. However, your code is correct, and that is the way to code.

Comment: The .Clear() methods are sync, Task.Delay() cannot emulate that.

Answer (score 4):

StateHasChanged() does not perform or force a Render, it only requests one.
That request can only be honored when the main thread is released for a bit, either in an await or when the eventhandling is finished.

When you don't have any async work you can simulate it with Task.Delay(1). But you do have to `await` so your method must return Task and must be awaited itself.

```
private async Task Search()  // call it from an Async method
{
  _loading = false;
  //StateHasChanged();  // not needed
  await Task.Delay(1);  // here the UI gets updated
  Mails.Clear();
  Licenses.Clear();
  Callings.Clear();
  Supports.Clear();
  Leads.Clear();
  search();            // tricky naming
  _loading = true;
  //StateHasChanged(); // not needed
}
```

Comment: Agree with you, but it's hard to know what each method does if you can't see it - I try not to make too many assumptions when answering.  My method is async and if the only way to do that is add an await Task.Delay then OK.  I added the 3 seconds so you can see it working.  I normally use a Task.Yield, but there's a lot of urban myth and voodoo around using it.

Comment: You can see they are not awaited. And something has to or the UI won't budge.

Comment: You can assume, but you can't be sure.  There could be an async warning on `search();`.  I've learnt that the hard way!  And yes something needs to yield for the UI to update!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis If there is an async warning on `search()`, it is still not awaited, that is, still called synchronously, that is, the execution still cannot return to the rendederer so that it could render. So it does not matter if `search()` is declared as `async` or not, it only matters that it's not awaited.